# Retrieving the numeric variable value of a list in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a problem with TCL script.
in below code I have a list:

```
set arcs {
    {a b $myVar(0)} {b a $myVar(1)} {b c $myVar(2)} {c f $myVar(3)} {b d $myVar(4)}
}
```

in $myVar($i) stored a numeric value.
and I have a function such as this :

```
proc myProc arcs {
    foreach arc $arcs {
    lassign $arc v1 v2 cost
    dict set graph $v1 $v2 $cost
    }
    return $graph
}
```

I called function :

```
myProc $arcs
```

but in the function, I can`t retrieving to numeric the value stored in $ab($i) and only name of variables stored in the $cost. such as this:

```
$v1 ----> a
$v2 ----> b
$cost ----> $myVar(0)
```

please tell me how I can pass the values of variables to function. such as this:

```
$v1 ----> a
$v2 ----> b
$cost ----> 25    /// value of $myVar(0)
```

I am new in tcl and I can`t solve the problem. I will really appreciate for your aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two-fold. Firstly, the input list doesn't have the value of the variable but rather a literal string, and secondly the context in which you need the value is not the context in which the value is known. To fix this, we need to detect when to apply the fix (`regexp` is my favourite approach) and in that case, to use `upvar 1` to bring the variable in question into temporary scope with a nice name so that we can replace the cost with its value.

```
proc myProc {arcs} {
    foreach arc $arcs {
        lassign $arc v1 v2 cost
        # Detect if we've got something we want to interpret as a variable use
        if {[regexp {^\$(.*)$} $cost -> varName]} {
            # NOTE: DO NOT USE [upvar 1 $varName cost] BECAUSE WE ARE IN A LOOP!
            # IGNORING THAT WILL DESTROY YOUR DATA.
            upvar 1 $varName var
            set cost $var
        }
        dict set graph $v1 $v2 $cost
    }
    return $graph
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[subst $cost]`. Note that `myVar` must be visible in the procedure's scope.

To elaborate:

```
proc myProc arcs {
    global myVar
    foreach arc $arcs {
        lassign $arc v1 v2 cost
        dict set graph $v1 $v2 [subst $cost]
    }
    return $graph
}
```

The variable `myVar` is made visible by the command `global` (if it isn't global, `upvar` might do). When inserting values in the dictionary, the value of `cost` is passed through `subst` to perform the variable substitution from `$myVar(index)`.

It is possible to simplify that to this:

```
proc myProc arcs {
    global myVar
    foreach arc $arcs {
        dict set graph {*}[subst $arc]
    }
    return $graph
}
```

Though this code is less clear.

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm)

Comment: @Ivy is the array `myVar` visible in the `proc` like Peter outlined?

Comment: Dear Peter.Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use braces, no substitution is performed and the literal value is used.
I would change the initialization to use a list:

```
set arcs [list \
    [list a b $myVar(0)] \
    [list b a $myVar(1)] \
    [list b c $myVar(2)] \
    [list c f $myVar(3)] \
    [list b d $myVar(4)] \
]
```

Comment: Dear Brad.Thank for your answer.